# How to average pair in list through iteration of list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples, average

[image: sample image][image]

I'm getting 2 pixels in red circle and 1 pixel in orange circle through intersection between line and contour.

It's hard to calculate distance between red circle and orange circle through `math.dist()` since I'm having 2 pixels in red circle which is very close. So, I tried to calculate the average of the 2 pixels in red circle first then only calculate the distance required. However, I'm stuck in appending the new average point into the existing list.

The target that I wish to achieve is no matter how many points are close with each other, those points are averaged and in the end I'm only getting only 2 points to calculate the distance.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/jay/Desktop/a.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gry,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cnt,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#visualize full contour
fullContour = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0], thresh.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(fullContour, cnt,-1, (255,255,255), 1)

cntPoints = []

for c in cnt:
    for cc in c:
        for ccc in cc:
            cntPoints.append((ccc[0], ccc[1]))

for i in range (len(cnt)):
    
    singleContour = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0], thresh.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
    
    cv2.drawContours(singleContour, cnt[i], -1, (255,255,255), 1)
    
    visualSingleContour = singleContour.copy()
    
    for _ in range (10):
        
        line_blank_mask = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0], thresh.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
        
        top = [np.random.randint(0,285),0]
        bottom = [np.random.randint(0,285), 305*2]
        
        cv2.line(visualSingleContour, (top[0],top[1]), (bottom[0],bottom[1]), (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.line(line_blank_mask, (top[0],top[1]), (bottom[0],bottom[1]), (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_4)
        
        comparedMask = cv2.bitwise_and(singleContour, line_blank_mask)
        
        points = []
        distance = []

        for x in range (visualSingleContour.shape[1]):
            for y in range (visualSingleContour.shape[0]):

                if comparedMask[y][x][0] == 255:
                    points.append([x,y])
        
        print(points)

        plt.subplot(1,3,1)
        plt.imshow(fullContour)
        plt.subplot(1,3,2)
        plt.imshow(visualSingleContour)
        plt.subplot(1,3,3)
        plt.imshow(comparedMask)
        plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: Add `print()` statements so you can see what's actually happening in the loop.

Comment: Off-topic: You should note that comparing the x and y components of the two points in isolation like that doesn't actually indicate how far apart they actually are.

Comment: @martineau Any better approach would you like to share to overcome the current issue ?

Comment: Using euclidian distance.

Comment: I didn't say your approach was wrong, just that the way you are determining whether the distance between pairs of points was bogus. To do it precisely use [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot). If speed is an issue, you could (manually) compute the distance² and avoid calling `sqrt()`.

Comment: Also note that if you want this to work when there are more than two points which are all close together, you *will* need to use a different approach.

Comment: @Guimoute, yeah I'm going to use euclidean distance to calculate the distance between points.

Comment: @martineau, Noted, thanks for your advice, I will look into math.hypot() and explore different approaches as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get the mean of a bunch of points would be to use the .mean function in numpy like in the following code:

```
myPoints = np.array([[95, 132], [95, 132], [95, 239], [94, 132]])
pointMean = myPoints.mean(axis=0)
print(pointMean)
```

output:

```
[ 94.75 158.75]
```

Now for your code all we need to do is separate out points we want to find the average of.  If most points are closely bunched and only one is far away, we can use zscore to remove any point that is further than 1 standard deviation away like so:

```
tempList = np.array([[95, 132], [96, 132], [134, 239]])

z= stats.zscore(tempList, axis=0)
print(z)
```

output:

```
[[-0.7344706  -0.70710678]
 [-0.67938531 -0.70710678]
 [ 1.41385591  1.41421356]]
```

now we can filter the original tempList by only the rows that have one or both x and y values < 1 and calculate the average of that.  We do this like so:

```
z = list([x<1 and y<1 for x,y in z])

newList = tempList[[not x for x in z]]
tempList = tempList[z]
newList = tempList.mean(axis=0)
print(newList)
```

output:

```
[ 95.5 132. ]
```

Here is the full code working an a list with many points closely bunched together:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

tempList = np.array([[95, 132], [96, 132], [94, 133], [134, 239], [95, 131]])

z= stats.zscore(tempList, axis=0)
z = list([abs(x)<1 and abs(y)<1 for x,y in z])

newList = tempList[[not x for x in z]]
tempList = tempList[z]

newList = np.concatenate([[tempList.mean(axis=0)], newList])
print(newList)
```

output:

```
[[ 95. 132.]
 [134. 239.]]
```

If your data is more complicated, say it also has many points bunched around the [134, 239] point, we would need a more robust way to split the two main bunches. Regardless, the .mean function is an excellent way to find the average point of a collection of points.

If you have many points around [95, 132] and many points around [132, 239] area and you know there will always be a big gap between the two groups relative to each groups standard deviation, a simple solution is to find the index of the greatest euclidian difference. Here is full code.

```
tempList = np.array([[95, 132], [96, 132], [132, 239], [131, 239], [94, 131], 
                    [94, 133], [134, 239], [95, 131], [133, 238]])

tempList = np.array(sorted(tempList, key=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x)))
diffs = [abs(np.linalg.norm(tempList[i]-tempList[i+1])) for i in range(len(tempList)-1)]
split_i = np.argmax(diffs)+1
group_1, group_2 = tempList[:split_i], tempList[split_i:]
newList = np.concatenate([[group_1.mean(axis=0)], [group_2.mean(axis=0)]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to append the output into the existing list ?
So, I have 2 points in the end to compute euclidean distance.

Comment: Sometimes I'm facing error when there are some points bunched around the [134, 239] point and resulted inaccurate output. 

Is it possible to separate them into 2 different main bunches and perform the same method using .mean function ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the part where the two points ("current" and "previous") are far enough to be considered distinct. in that case, you want the current point to be appended to the list.

```py
import numpy as np

points = [(95, 132), (96, 132), (134, 239)]
unique_points = []

for previous, current in zip(points, points[1:]):    
    if (current[0] - previous[0]) < 3 or (current[1] - previous[1]) < 3:
        totalx = np.average((current[0], previous[0]))       
        totaly = np.average((current[1], previous[1]))        
        unique_points.append((totalx, totaly))
    else:
        unique_points.append(current)

print(unique_points)
# >>> [(95.5, 132.0), (134, 239)]
```

Comment: I think my current code logic only works if there are only 2 points which are close to each other. 

I tried to increase the points to [(95, 132), (96, 132), (97, 132), (134, 239)]. 

It returns 3 points and not 2 points in the new_points.

Comment: @peter: The overall gist of this answer is correct — i.e. you have to add both points to the list when they're not close to one another. The problem is your overall approach doesn't work when there are multiple consecutive points "close together".

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the average distance between those pixels maybe you could consider a bit different solution.
As this is a coordinate system you can get the sides of a right triangle and calculate diagonal (a_squered + b_squered = c_squered) to the
first and to the second close pixel. (It is either a right triangle or a straight line, which you can consider as a right triangle with one side of the length of zero.)
Afterwords you just get the average of those distances.

```py
import math

tempList = [(95, 132), (96, 132), (134, 239)]

a1 = abs(tempList[0][0] - tempList[2][0])
b1 = abs(tempList[0][1] - tempList[2][1])

a2 = abs(tempList[1][0] - tempList[2][0])
b2 = abs(tempList[1][1] - tempList[2][1])

c1 = math.sqrt(a1**2 + b1**2)
c2 = math.sqrt(a2**2 + b2**2)

print('--------------------------------------------')
print('1st pixel distances (x, y) = (' + str(a1) + ', ' + str(b1) + ')')
print('2nd pixel distances (x, y) = (' + str(a2) + ', ' + str(b2) + ')')
print('--------------------------------------------')
print('distance to 1st pixel = ' + str(c1))
print('distance to 2nd pixel = ' + str(c2))
print('--------------------------------------------')
print('average distance = ' + str((c1 + c2) / 2))
```

Result:

```py
'''
--------------------------------------------
1st pixel distances (x, y) = (39, 107)
2nd pixel distances (x, y) = (38, 107)
--------------------------------------------
distance to 1st pixel = 113.8859078200635
distance to 2nd pixel = 113.54734695271397
--------------------------------------------
average distance = 113.71662738638872
'''
```

**Addition** 
Tryed to simulate your actual data a bit. If you have a series of coordinates with the last one as a point_0 (the one whose distance to the others you want to calculate).
In this sample data there are some close to each other and some not. Closeness is defined using variable **"closeness_x_y = (4, 2)"**, meaning you can define what distance of x or y
coordinate which you consider close enaugh to calculate averages.
There are a few functions defined for making the code more readable. There is a list of pairs of coordinates sorted by x, y except the last one which is here for calculation as a refference point.
There is a double for loop creating  groups of pairs of coordinates or just a single pair depending on given closeness_x_y variable. It is defined by is_close() function.
Having the pixels grouped in a way that you define it is quite simple to calculate the distance or average distance to point_0 (function get_distance).
You asked about how fast it is - well it depends on the actual data that you have on your side. Anyway you can test it and see if it fits you or not. Regards...

```py
import math

tempList = [(63, 99), (94, 132), (95, 131), (95, 132), (96, 130), (96, 132), (84, 120), (84, 121), (85, 122), (92, 122), (134, 239), (140, 142), (154, 130), (168, 112), (178, 96)]

group_dct = {}
group_lst = []
done_lst = []
grp =  0
lngth = len(tempList) 
point_0 = tempList[lngth - 1]
finished = False
closeness_x_y = (4, 2)

# ---------------------------------------------
def is_close(pix_1 = (), pix_2 = ()):
    if abs(pix_1[0] - pix_2[0]) <= closeness_x_y[0] and abs(pix_1[1] - pix_2[1]) <= closeness_x_y[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_processed(pix):
    if pix in done_lst:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_key(k):
    if k in group_dct.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_distance(from_pix, to_pix = []):
    c = 0
    c_sum = 0
    if to_pix == []:
        return 0
    for i in range(len(to_pix)):
        dist_x = abs(from_pix[0] - to_pix[i][0])
        dist_y = abs(from_pix[1] - to_pix[i][1])
        c = c + math.sqrt(dist_x**2 + dist_y**2)
        c_sum = c_sum + c   
    distance = c_sum / len(to_pix)
    return distance

# --------------------------------------------       

for i in range(lngth-1):
    if finished:
        break
    if not is_processed(tempList[i]):
        group_lst.append(tempList[i])
        done_lst.append(tempList[i])
    finished = True
    for k in range(lngth-2):
        if i + k + 1 < lngth:           
            if is_close(tempList[i + k], tempList[i + k + 1]):
                if not is_processed(tempList[i + k + 1]):
                    group_lst.append(tempList[i + k + 1])
                    done_lst.append(tempList[i + k + 1])
                else:
                    pass
            else:   
                group_dct['G_' + str(grp)] = group_lst
                group_lst = []
                grp += 1
                group_lst.append(tempList[i + k + 1])

            if is_key('G_' + str(grp)):
                group_dct['G_' + str(grp)] = group_lst
            else:
                group_dct['G_' + str(grp)] = group_lst


for k, v in group_dct.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        print('Group ' + k + ' ' + str(v) + ' --> distance from point_0 is ' + str(get_distance(point_0, v)))
    else:
        print('Group ' + k + ' ' + str(v) + ' --> average distance from point_0 is ' + str(get_distance(point_0, v)))
```

Note that you are free to manipulate closeness simply by changing the closeness_x_y variable. Here it is (4, 2) which means that any distance within 4 pixels on x axis and 2 pixels on y axis is considered close. Anything out of those limits is not close enough.
Result is below. Within result you can see the groupings that were done.

```py
''' R e s u l t :
Group G_0 [(63, 99)] --> distance from point_0 is 115.03912377969506
Group G_1 [(94, 132), (95, 131), (95, 132), (96, 130), (96, 132)] --> average distance from point_0 is 271.15270270060057
Group G_2 [(84, 120), (84, 121), (85, 122)] --> average distance from point_0 is 194.04925715560103
Group G_3 [(92, 122)] --> distance from point_0 is 89.8443097808648
Group G_4 [(134, 239)] --> distance from point_0 is 149.61617559608987
Group G_5 [(140, 142)] --> distance from point_0 is 59.665735560705194
Group G_6 [(154, 130)] --> distance from point_0 is 41.617304093369626
Group G_7 [(168, 112)] --> distance from point_0 is 18.867962264113206
'''
```

Comment: Does it handy and compute fast enough when I'm having more than 3 points ? 
As my current approach is using for loop to draw random lines on image. 

It's hard to determine how many points are intersected every time.

Comment: It should be fast, but it depends on your loops. I don't know how long is your actual tempList. And how many group points you have. It is irrelevant is it 2, 3 or 5 pixels.