# How to calculate the average of 2 different numpy array pairs of bunch of points in list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a numpy array pair list

```
[[214,295], [215, 294], [229, 226], [229, 227]]
```

After calculating the average of the bunch of points using the Z score, the result I have is

```
[[222.0, 260.5], [214.0, 295.0], [229.0, 226.0]]
```

Expected result
[[average of `[214, 295], [215, 294]`] , [average of `[229, 226], [229, 227]`]

It should always return 2 points instead of more than 3 points. Do I need to calculate a new Z score separately?

Another example that I can bring up for discussion

`[[95, 132], [96, 132], [94, 133], [134, 239], [95, 131]]`

Current output

```
[[ 95. 132.], [134. 239.]]
```

If the data has many points bunched around the [134, 239] point, I would like to have a more robust way to split the two main bunches.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

tempList = np.array([[214,295], [215, 294],[229, 226], [229, 227]])

z= stats.zscore(tempList, axis=0)
z = list([abs(x)<1 and abs(y)<1 for x,y in z])

newList = tempList[[not x for x in z]]

tempList = tempList[z]

newList = np.concatenate([[tempList.mean(axis=0)], newList])
print(newList)
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected result?

Comment: So, you want to average two points at a time?

Comment: @Mark, the expected result is only returning 2 numpy array in 1 list. 

[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]

Comment: @Tim ROberts 
Correct, I want to average 2 points at a time if they are close together just like the list I posted.

As you can see, the 1st 2 pairs of X values are 214 and 215 whereas Y values are 295 and 294. They are considered close since only difference by 1. This is the 1st pair I want to average it. 

If I have another numpy array which are further away from the 1st 2 pairs yet they are close just like 229 for X value, 226 and 227 for Y values, I would like to average it again.

Comment: you need to look into kmeans and clustering. That is by far the closest to what I can understand what you want. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: @M Z I linked related posts at here, perhaps it helps you to understand more on my current issues. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930103/how-to-average-pair-in-list-through-iteration-of-list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948928/how-to-find-average-distance-between-a-bunch-of-points-in-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to do what you describe just by reshaping the array:

```
import numpy as np
tempList = np.array([[214,295], [215, 294],[229, 226], [229, 227]])
tempList = tempList.reshape( (-1,2,2) )
print(tempList)
print("---")
print( tempList.mean( axis=1 ) )
```

Output:

```
[[[214 295]
  [215 294]]

 [[229 226]
  [229 227]]]
---
[[214.5 294.5]
 [229.  226.5]]
```

Comment: Implemented this code, it works as expected. 
However, I'm facing an issue about the tempList. 

I'm looping to obtain the tempList, so the length of tempList is not always 4. 
** I should mention in the post earlier. 

 Is it possible to make the code more flexible ?

Comment: It should work as is with any even number of points.  I've tried it.

Comment: @ Tim Roberts, I'm having this issue "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (2,2)" when detected 3 number of points. 

So, current method will not work for odd number of points ?

Comment: My code doesn't say `reshape( (2,2) )`, it says `reshape( (-1,2,2) )`.  The -1 means the first dimension will be as big as it needs to be.

Comment: I know, but that's the error when the length of tempList is odd number.
For example, 
([[190,190], [215, 294],[229, 226]])

Comment: Well, of course.  How can you average "pairs" of points if there aren't pairs?  What do you expect to happen in that case?